# ambiguous argument 'HEAD..origin/master' but no branch named master

Tags: git, shell, github, zsh, iterm2

**EDIT**

When I create a local git repository using `git init`
the git repo initiates itself with a branch named "main" but in addition I immediatly get the error:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD..origin/master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

I don't have a "master" branch: when I run on my local computer `git branch -a` I get the following branches:

```
* main
```

**As @Joachim Sauer noted it:**
"something configured your shell prompt to print information about your git repository. That something assumes that a master branch always exists, which is wrong. You need to find out how that prompt is configured and fix that. It's not really a git problem, but a problem of whatever is used to show your shell prompt."

I work on a MacOS 12.4 and I use iterm2 with zsh.

Do you know how I can suppress this error message ?

Comment: Did you try to `git branch -a` (to show remote branch) or `git checkout master` to check if you can reach remote `master` branch ?

Comment: Find out where `HEAD..origin/master` is used and then replace it with `HEAD..origin/main`.

Comment: If you get the error message even when you do not issue a Git command, then it originates most likely from the shell prompt generator.

Comment: that's indeed the case

Comment: ````git checkout master```` answers ````fatal: invalid reference: master```` and ````git branch -a```` shows ````* main```` ````remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/main```` ````remotes/origin/main```` so no ````master```` branch anywhere

Comment: Does your current branch have an incorrect upstream configured? (I'm not very knowledgable about upstream configuration because I don't use them a lot.) Have a look into `.git/config` and see if you find `master` mentioned suspiciously somewhere.

Comment: I opened all .git files and none mentionned a suspicious ```master``` but I'll try to go to the main configuration files of git see if I can find something

Comment: What is the specific command that is setup to run on the shell prompt?

Comment: I don't understand you comment @eftshift0 . Where can I find the command set up to run on the shell prompt ?

Comment: I guess you need to _start_ by checking the value of `PS1` (with `echo $PS1`) but I am not that knowledgeable on the subject.

Comment: ```echo $PS1``` returns ```$(build_prompt)```

Comment: @T.Walter: so *something* configured your shell prompt (apparently zsh, according to google) to print information about your git repository. That *something* assumes that a `master` branch always exists, which is wrong. You need to find out how that prompt is configured and fix that. It's not **really** a git problem, but a problem of whatever is used to show your shell prompt.

Comment: `build_prompt` is from `oh-my-zsh`, a `zsh` add-on with prompt themes and other customizations. You probably have a line in your `~/.zshrc` file that looks something like `plugins=(nvm git autosuggestions)`. Removing the reference to `git` and restarting the shell should help. Removing all of the references to `oh-my-zsh` (my approach) is also an option.

Comment: I suppressed it but this didn't change anything. I also went into the file ```git.zsh``` (same folder as ```~/.zshrc```) suppressed the function ```function git_better_master() {
  if [[ -n ${$(command git remote | grep $ZSH_GIT_REMOTE_NAME 2>/dev/null)} ]];then
    echo $ZSH_GIT_REMOTE_NAME/master
  else
    echo master
  fi
}``` -> didn't change anything.

Comment: @Gairfowl from this website: https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/blob/master/plugins/git/git.plugin.zsh I copy paste the function ```function git_main_branch() {
  command git rev-parse --git-dir &>/dev/null || return
  local ref
  for ref in refs/{heads,remotes/{origin,upstream}}/{main,trunk,mainline,default}; do
    if command git show-ref -q --verify $ref; then
      echo ${ref:t}
      return
    fi
  done
  echo master
}``` into this same file git.zsh but it didn't change anything either

Comment: It might be a bit easier to just remove `oh-my-zsh` rather than trying to figure out how it's broken - [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/963874/uninstall-oh-my-zsh) describes how.

Comment: Another option is to override the prompt that `omz` supplies with something you build yourself.  Start with adding something simple like `PROMPT='%~ >'` to the bottom of the `~/.zshrc` file.  You can find a number of answer here on SO that describe how to customize the prompt for your requirements.

Comment: @Gairfowl thank you so much, I think you didn't provide the last link on your comment : "You can find a number of answer here"

Comment: Sorry, I didn't phrase that clearly (or even with correct grammar :).  I just meant that you can find a lot of answers on Stack Overflow and other Stack Exchange sites on customizing prompts; it's a common topic.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find the file which assumed that a `master`branch always exists.

As a way around:

**When I initiate the repo locally**

The error message is `HEAD..master`  and I :

1. rename my local `main` branch into `master` using `git branch -m main master`
2. do a first empty commit using `git commit --allow-empty -n -m "first commit"`

Then the message disappears.

**When I then link it to a remote repo**

The message reappears, stating: `HEAD..origin/master`.

On github:

1. I change the name of the branch main to master

Then locally:

2. `git fetch`
3. `git merge`

and the message disappears again !